# problem withAsync SqlComman

Tags: c#, sqlconnection, iasyncresult

I have problem with Timeout, when I run a command through app, a timeout exception is thrown, but when I run it directly in sql there is no timeout exception!

my SP take about 11 min when I run it directly.
for solving this issue, I found below code here, but It doesn't work properly!
Immediately after beginExecute, IAsyncResult.iscomplete become true !!!!

where is the problem ?

```
IAsyncResult result = command.BeginExecuteNonQuery();

    int count = 0;
    while (!result.IsCompleted)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting ({0})", count++);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Command complete. Affected {0} rows.",
    command.EndExecuteNonQuery(result));
```

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase the command timeout instead ([SqlCommand.CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx)) which by default is 30 seconds.

Comment: I did not know that there is a another timeout in Command!

Thanks, My main problem is solved!
But what happen to IAsync ?

Comment: Are you getting any results? What are you specifying as the command text?

Answer (score 0):

A connection string will default to a 15 second timeout. See on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28VS.71%29.aspx).

You can change the timeout on the connection string to last longer (`connection timeout=600`, for a 10 minute timeout).

See [this](http://connectionstrings.com/) site for more about connection strings.

Having said that, you should look at optimizing your database and/or stored procedure. 11 minutes for a stored procedure is very very long. Do you have the correct indexes on your tables? Is you stored procedure written in the most optimal way?

**Update:**

Have you made sure you are using the correct command and that the results are correct? IsComplete being true almost immediately suggests that the command has indeed finished.

Comment: Thanks for answering,
I increased timeout in connection string but it did not work.
in this sp I have to work on 3 table hierarchically,
I have 3 cursor and used them hierarchically for this 3 table!

Comment: I have to read all of these record and insert them for newyaer so I need new IDs for child tables